# Principles of currency formatting for users in a different locale

Tags: localization, internationalization, currency-formatting

There's a heap of resources available on how currencies should be formatted for different locales.

What I am having much more trouble gaining an understanding of is what strategy or position one should take when formatting a given currency for a *reader* (ie. a user) when that user is in a different locale to the currency.

My question specifically relates to web applications but that is probably irrelevant.

For example, consider an Australian user. Their "natural" currency presentation is [A]$10,293.56. In other words, period is used as the decimal separator, comma as a thousands separator. And $/A$ indicates the currency.

Let's say I want to show the above Australian amount to a German user (ie. a German-speaking user operating a German browser, probably located in Germany).

I could present the currency [at least] two different ways:

1. [A]$10,293.56 -- In other words I just use "Australian formatting" because it is an Australian currency.
2. [A]$10.293,56 -- I use German decimal presentation with the Australian currency symbols.

In the latter case it might be beneficial to move the currency indicator to somewhere else even (but one example is: 10.293.56 A$).

The specific situation concerns accounting systems where different currencies need to be displayed relative to a user's "native" currency.

It seems fairly obvious [to me] that using Option 1 is open to misinterpretation because of the different period/comma use, so Option 2 seems at least "sensible".

But I am wondering if there is indeed any document "common practice" in this area. Obviously it's not just the formatting of the number that could potentially get funky, it's the placement of the currency name &/or symbol.

Answer (score 1):

Most of the formatting (the digits, the decimal and group separators, minus sign, the currency position) are not determined by the currency, but by the locale.

If you show info to a German user, you use German style everywhere.